# Update keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm pretty new to python, started learning a few days ago... I came across practice project where we are to create a password locker which stores accounts and their respective password.

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
             'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
             'luggage': '12345'}

import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name
if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

That's the code. So I thought of a way of updating the `PASSWORDS` dictionary with the new info if the account was not present prior. So I added these lines of codes to the else statement

```
    print('Input the password for the said account to update the info.')
    PASSWORDS[account] = input()
    print('Info updated!')
```

The issue I'm facing now is that the values added to the dictionary get not persisted after the program finishes.

Comment: If you want data to persist after exiting the program, you need to write it to a file in some way (and then load that file when starting the program). For example, JSON would be a good way to store a dictionary.

Comment: If you like dictionaries then i will suggest you to look into YAML files and then the Python Yaml module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password management is always a very delicate topic, but since you are just starting and not asking about security, let's se how we can load and write a simple JSON file in a very easy way.

First, lets move the actual data to a separate file, wich we can name as `database.json`:

```
{"email": "F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6",
 "blog": "VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt",
 "luggage": "12345"}
```

Then we change the application code like this:

```
#!/usr/env python3
"""
 pw.py - An insecure password locker program.
"""
import sys
import pyperclip
import json
import os


# The path to the database file
DB_FILE = "~/Desktop/database.json"


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print('Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password')
        sys.exit()

    account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name
    db = os.path.expanduser(DB_FILE)
    with open(db) as f:
        data = json.load(f)  # Load a dictionary for disk

    if account in data:
        pyperclip.copy(data[account])
        print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
    else:
        print('There is no account named ' + account)
        print('Input the password for the said account to update the info.')
        new_passwd = {account: input()}  # create a dictionary with the new account data
        data.update(new_passwd)  # update the main dictionary with the new data

        with open(db, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)  # convert to JSON and write to disk

        print('Info updated!')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For such a simple task, there are a number of file formats that you could use. JSON is a format that maps to Python dictionaries in a way that is both logical and easy to understand, but you could also implement it in CSV without adding much complication. But in this kind of applications, you will very soon feel the need for something more practical and robust. For instance, as your database grows, it may start to be impractical to load the whole database into memory. And it could raise even more security issues.

Take your time learning the basics like these and then explore the [module `sqlite`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html). It allows for SQL usage in a single-file relational database and will pave your way for both powerful applications and further learning.